# Why is Kinetic Energy = (-) Total Energy and Potential Energy = 2 $\times$ Total Energy?

Tags: forces, energy, energy-conservation, virial-theorem

I came across this relation while reading on the Bohr atomic model. Are there any other forces for which these relations hold good?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48713/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/125992/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've discovered the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem).

The virial theorem tells us that for a bound system where the potential energy $V$ is given by an equation:

$$ V(r) \propto r^{-n} $$

The average kinetic energy $T$ and average potential energy $U$ are related by:

$$ 2T = -nU $$

For the electrostatic force $V(r) \propto r^{-1}$ so $n = 1$ and:

$$ 2T = -U \tag{1} $$

The total energy is $E = T + U$ so using equation (1) to substitute for $U$ gives us:

$$ E = -T$$

and substituting for $U$ gives:

$$ E = \tfrac{1}{2}U $$

The example you've found is for the electrostatic force, but exactly the same applies to the gravitational force. Indeed, the first evidence for dark matter was when [Fritz Zwicky used the virial theorem](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2007/ph210/sugarbaker2/) to show that the velocities in a galaxy cluster were higher than they should be.

Answer (score 0):

This is true for central potential problems. Because in that case, both potential energy and kinetic energy are in (1/r) terms. Also, Potential energy is negative and its magnitude is twice that of Kinetic energy . Thus we conclude that only the mathematics of this problem allows it to be expressed as the formula u proposed and it is general for any central force problems

Comment: This answer is wrong. You might want to read about the [Virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem).